# Structure of structures to array

Tags: matlab, structure

Is there a fast/nice way to convert a structure of structures to an array?

```
s1 = struct('v', 1);
s2 = struct('v', 2);
s = struct('s1', s1, 's2', s2);
```

I expect an array of `.v`:

```
[1, 2]
```

**Reason**:
I need to pass a Simulink.Parameter (which is a struct of structs of structs etc) to a C S-function and I was thinking about serializing it by making it an array of doubles (which is contiguous in memory) and then I recast it to my struct definition in C.

Comment: Do you want an array of structs (you can't strictly have, but you can use a CellArray) or do you want an array of `.v` values?

Comment: Give us some input and expected output for us to work with?

Comment: @Divakar I expect an array of doubles. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This resursive function works for any depth level and is more compact:

```
function arr = f_struct2array(S, arr)
    if (isa(S, 'double'))
        arr = [arr S];
    else
        SNames = fieldnames(S); 
        for i = 1:numel(SNames) 
            arr = f_struct2array(S.(SNames{i}), arr);
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:**

```
s1 = struct('v', 10);
s2 = struct('v', 20);
s3 = struct('v', 30);
s4 = struct('v', 40);

s = struct('s1', s1, 's2', s2,'s3', s3, 's4', s4);

n1 = fieldnames(s);
for k1 = 1:numel(fieldnames(s))
    array1(k1) = getfield(getfield(s,char(n1(k1))),'v');
end
```

**Output**

```
array1 =

    10    20    30    40
```

**Method 2:** Use `cell array` for the same result -

```
cell_array1 = struct2cell(s);
for k1 = 1:numel(fieldnames(s))
    array1(k1) = cell_array1{k1,1}.v;
end
```

**Method 3:** Use `cell array` without loop for the same result -

```
array1 = cellfun(@(x) x(:,1).v,struct2cell(s))';
```

**Extended Part:** This is for a case where we have a struct of struct of struct..(inception style?)

```
%%// Let us create a struct of struct of struct as "s"
s11 = struct('v', 10);
s12 = struct('v', 20);
s13 = struct('v', 30);
s14 = struct('v', 40);

s1 = struct('s11', s11, 's12', s12,'s13', s13, 's14', s14);

s11 = struct('v', 110);
s12 = struct('v', 120);
s13 = struct('v', 130);
s14 = struct('v', 140);

s2 = struct('s11', s11, 's12', s12,'s13', s13, 's14', s14);

s = struct('s1', s1, 's2', s2);

%%// Processing
cell1 = struct2cell(s);
array1 = cellfun(@(x) x(:,:).v,struct2cell(vertcat(cell1{:})))'
```

**Output**

```
array1 =

    10    20    30    40
   110   120   130   140
```

**Extended Part 2:** If you want to go one more level deeper, use this -

```
%%// Let us create a struct of struct of struct as "s_1"
s11 = struct('v', 10);
s12 = struct('v', 20);
s13 = struct('v', 30);
s14 = struct('v', 40);

s1 = struct('s11', s11, 's12', s12,'s13', s13, 's14', s14);

s11 = struct('v', 110);
s12 = struct('v', 120);
s13 = struct('v', 130);
s14 = struct('v', 140);

s2 = struct('s11', s11, 's12', s12,'s13', s13, 's14', s14);

s_1 = struct('s1', s1, 's2', s2);


%%// Let us create a struct of struct of struct as "s_2"
s11 = struct('v', 0.1);
s12 = struct('v', 0.2);
s13 = struct('v', 0.3);
s14 = struct('v', 0.4);

s1 = struct('s11', s11, 's12', s12,'s13', s13, 's14', s14);

s11 = struct('v', 0.01);
s12 = struct('v', 0.02);
s13 = struct('v', 0.03);
s14 = struct('v', 0.04);

s2 = struct('s11', s11, 's12', s12,'s13', s13, 's14', s14);

s_2 = struct('s1', s1, 's2', s2);

%% Finally you would have s
s = struct('s_1', s_1, 's_2', s_2);

%%// Processing
cell1 = struct2cell(s);
for k2 = 1:2
    val1 = cell1{k2,1};
    t1 = struct2cell(val1);
    for k1=1:2
        array1(k1,:,k2) = cellfun(@(x) x(:,:).v,struct2cell(t1{k1,:}))';
    end
end
```

**Output**

```
array1(:,:,1) =

    10    20    30    40
   110   120   130   140


array1(:,:,2) =

    0.1000    0.2000    0.3000    0.4000
    0.0100    0.0200    0.0300    0.0400
```

**Note:** If you intend to go more levels deeper, just define more for loops and increase the dimension for array1.

Comment: What if the depth is larger than 2? Let's say I don't know the depth.

Comment: As long as the final array is expected to be 1D, it should be fine.

Comment: I'm thinking about a recursive in-depth pass combined with struct2cell.

Comment: I'll test your algo on my larger struct.

Comment: @remus Check out the edited code for a depth of 4. Only the input is changed.

Comment: @remus Check out the `struct2cell` method at the end of the edited code.

Comment: By depth I meant struct of struct of struct: e.g. s.s1.s11.v. Or even deeper.

Comment: @remus How would you store such data into a double array. Should that be a 2D matrix then or just vertically concatenate to keep it 1D?

Comment: @remus Check out **Extended Part** for one level deeper case.

Comment: Just concatenated. I need to pass a Simulink.Parameter (which is a struct of structs of structs etc) to a C S-function and I was thinking about serializing it by making it an array of doubles (which is contiguous in memory) and then I recast it to my struct definition in C.

Comment: @remus How deep is it exactly? Do you have a number on that?

Comment: s.s1.s11.v would be max.

Comment: @remus So the Extended part must work on that, right?

Comment: @remus Check out **Extended Part 2** for solving infinite level deep structs you might have. Hopefully this must settle it!